# Setting locale for Chinese characters in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, collation, localization

I am designing a Postgresql database that contains Chinese characters in certain tables (.e.g login, comments). Most tables are perfectly fine with ASCII characters.

From [Postgresql Locale Support](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/locale.html), the locale of the database can be set during creation. But setting a non-default `C` locale will degrade performance over sorting. Is it possible to specify locale per table or per column in Postgresql?

Answer (score 2):

You weren't far from finding it.
[Here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html)'s the documentation you're looking for.

Yes you can define a specific locale for chosen columns (from 9.1 version).